# Adding an image to a solution which won't compile and which can be navigated to

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

It often happens that I draw diagrams of how something is designed in my application, for example a tree-like structure in a dialog window with several steps that the user can answer by choosing yes and no.

[image]

Is it possible to include this image in my solution but not compile it?

And would it be possible to add a link to the image in my code so that I can simply click on the link, and it would open up the image for me in VS?

This way I wouldn't have to locate it on my disk.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an existing file to your project then right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer and select 'Add > Existing item'.  Set the `Build Action` to `Content` and the `Copy to output directory` to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.  The file will then be copied to the same folder as the EXE when you build.  You can access such a file at run time using a path like this:

```
Dim filePath = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "filename.ext")
```

Comment: I don't think (from the OP) that it has to be viewed during run-time, only from within VS. In that case, adding it as an item should do the job.

Comment: @AJD, it appears that you're correct. I read the "click on the link" part but missed the "open in VS" part. In that case, setting `Copy to output directory` to `Never copy` would be most appropriate.  Double-clicking the item in the Solution Explorer would open it but it may do so in an editor within VS. You might need to right-click and select 'Open With' to view it more appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. There is no solution to add a a link in my code that I could click and which would then open up the image, would it?